# customize shopping cart in oscommerce

Tags: oscommerce

I have a product with different attributes . like My product is computer and it has 1 GB Ram, 2 GB Ram and 4 GB Ram. I want that if user click at 1 Gb then this should be add to cart with 1 GB attribute with its price and if user click at 2 GB Ram then this should be Replace with 1 GB and its price.
Every Attribute should be linked like add to cart.

At this time with Os-commerce button add to cart this add all attributes in cart.
Any one can help that how this can be possible.

like one attribute display follow

2 GB RAM 2 X 1 GB Ram
PC2700 NONECC UNBUFFERED 184 PIN DDR DIMM


KR. '`


&opt_id=&opt_val=''" />

this is not doing any action
please help

Comment: This isn't a programming question. This is a store setup question.

Answer (score 0):

try this contribution.

http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,3610